# Create a windows service in vb6

Tags: vb6, windows-services, service

Is it possible to create a windows service in vb6? if yes, how?

Comment: Does it have to be VB6? If you can get to .NET it is infinitely easier.

Answer (score 4):

I've never tried it, but Desaware offer a commercial package, the [NT Service Toolkit](http://www.desaware.com/products/universalcom/ntservicetoolkit/index.aspx) that claims to allow you to host a VB6 DLL inside a Windows Service. Desaware was founded (and I think is still owned by) VB6 guru Dan Appleman, which is a good recommendation.

Comment: Back in the day... we used the NT Service Toolkit a lot.  It was great.  I don't recall ever having an issue with it.

Comment: Looks like he's still there.  Appleman is one of the best there is in VB6, and all the Desaware products I've seen are extremely reliable and well thought out.  (No, I don't work for them.)

Comment: The NT Service toolkit won't register in 64bit windows, it has issues with the SystemWow64 directory...

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft created a control to allow you to create services in VB6.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/170883

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175948/EN-US/

Yes, it works, is it the best way to create a service, no, but if VB6 is a requirement (you have a bunch of code you have to re-use), then I can state from experience that it works.  We have the original control from the January 1997 MSDN, however you can easily find it on the net if need be ( http://www.google.ca/search?q=ntsvc.ocx+download )

Comment: Bad code is bad code, and hacks are hacks.  This OCX is only as good as the person using it.  I've have used it in several servers to replace .Net servers written by contractors that was slow and buggy.  Not only did we improve performance by nearly a factor of 10, it doesn't need to be manually restarted weekly the way the bad .Net code did.

Comment: Please not that this OCX is not working no Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Like gouging your own eyes out with a spoon, it is technically possible but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Just follow the directions in this tutorial:

http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is possible to create a Windows service with VB6. To offer you advice, there are much better tools to use. I did it once as a proof of concept project, but never liked it well enough to try to use it for anything that we used in the company. A co-worker did do this for a production app and it was error prone. After he left we found out just how hard he was working to keep his service running and ended up replacing his app without reviewing his code. So my advice is, if you want to do it as an exercise go ahead, but if you are looking at this for a workable solution you should consider other tools. Here is a [link](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92) to one way to do it.