# What is event generation in linux and how are they generated to a process?

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel

I studied about signal that it is an event generation, but i am not clear that how an event is generated, who generates it and how a process comes to know that a event has been generated to it ?

Comment: [How signals are implemented in Linux](http://cs-pub.bu.edu/fac/richwest/cs591_w1/notes/wk3_pt2.PDF) and [The Linux Signals Handling Model](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3985)

Comment: [Implementation of Signals under Linux and Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671741/implementation-of-signals-under-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Event is noting but a response from an input or output. For example, if you type a key on your keyboard, it generates an event(Not directly, through some device driver) and your process which is waiting on the keyboard is notified by its driver.