# Why doesn't SIGINT handler work in my code?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, signals

I need my command line application to wait for <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in the main thread and then execute some deinitialization code and exit.

I tested this scenario with the following test program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void control_break_handler(int) { printf("\ncontrol_break_handler\n"); }

int main()
{
    printf("%s", "Before signal\n");

    int result = 0;

    struct sigaction sigact = {};
    result = sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    assert(result == 0);
    sigact.sa_handler = &control_break_handler;
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    result = sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact, NULL);
    assert(result == 0);

    sigset_t set;
    result = sigemptyset(&set);
    assert(result == 0);
    result = sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
    assert(result == 0);
    int sig;
    result = sigwait(&set, &sig);
    assert(result == 0);
    printf("\nsigwait returned %d, sig = %d\n", result, sig);

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

But it just prints

```
sigwait returned 0, sig = 2
```

after first <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and the "control_break_handler" called only after the second <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.
How do I execute deinitialization code on first <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>?
I use Ubuntu 13.04 x64.

**EDIT:** Ok, it seems I figured this out. I thrown away `sigaction` and added call to `sigprocmask` before `sigwait`. It seems to work just fine.

Comment: Don't use sigwait. You've registered your signal handler, it *will* be called before your application exits if the signal appears.

Comment: But then the main thread and hence the whole app immediately will exit. Do you mean I have to redesign the app to wait on worker threads not the SIGINT?

Comment: Well, your main app somewhere has to spin doing its work?...

Comment: Suppose my app schedules some actions to be fired by timer every minute so it doesn't spin and just need to wait for SIGINT.

Comment: Well you could do that. I think the point is that you have two ways of handling that signal. Synchronously with wait or asynchronously with a handler. Mostly people would assume that the signal is an unusual condition and handle it as an exception with a handler.

Comment: [Avoid using printf in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891065#16891065)

Comment: Additional to mask also set `sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;`   To restart functions if interrupted by handler (as handlers called asynchronously) [Read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942034/simple-linux-signal-handling/17942230#17942230)

Comment: @user835103 You welcome! ...using printf is immediate problem in your code. Remember always call safe function in signal handler and  handler should small and simple.