# C++: ctrl+d terminates program (ubuntu)

Tags: c++, cout, eof, clion

(New to C++)

I have this simple code (simplified for the question):

```
 int main()
{
    string currInput;
    while (getline(cin, currInput))
    {
    }
    cout << "wont be printed" << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

I have been debugging for a while and I probably miss something:

When running it and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (after some strings or right away), it does not print the string that is after the while loop. It just stop running. I thought it might be something with flushing so I added that too.
What am I missing?

PS: When running in debug, it mentions something about sighup signal.

Comment: _"it mention something about sighup signal"_ You probably want to add code to ignore the [`SIGHUP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551485/how-to-make-the-process-ignore-some-signallike-sighup-sigabrt-sigabort-sigint-e) signal.

Comment: We haven't learned about signals yet, and I couldnt fine any example that handles this, do you have any reference?

Comment: Check the link from my comment. It leads to a number of references in the answer and the comments.

Comment: Why do you press ctrl+d?

Comment: to send EOF string

Comment: So you are using some Unix flavor?

Comment: Ubuntu (short msg)

Comment: @kobi: how are you running that program?

Comment: with cLion (short msg)

Comment: Add a `\n` at the end of the string you output.

Comment: Still nothing. Also tried endl instead of flush.

Comment: Open terminal. Start the program. Press ctrl+d.

Comment: It closes the terminal window.

Comment: oops wait, missed the "start the program" part, how do you want me to compile it?

Comment: Try release and debug.

Comment: It seems to be working this way!
It's all cLion's fault? Is there a way to change it's behavior? can you try it on your machine with cLion (if you have it installed)?

Comment: The cLion console is not very reliable, apparently. (I've never used it but I've seen lots of problems reported here.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending EOF to stdin in Clion IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405577/sending-eof-to-stdin-in-clion-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with a lot of help from @manni and @rici, we found the problem.

It turns out to be a known problem in cLion.

see [sending EOF to stdin in Clion IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405577/sending-eof-to-stdin-in-clion-ide)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206849765-How-to-enter-EOF-Ctrl-z-in-Run-console-

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12514

Answer (score -2):

Your error is the while loop. You should not be using a loop here. What happens is it hits this line and attempts to get input. Regardless of whether you type in anything or not, if you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it will end the getline. But you have it in a while loop....so it'll hop back to the top of the loop and get another line...then another line....then another line. Welcome to your first infinite loop.

```
while (getline(cin, currInput))
{
}
```

The simplest thing would be to do just

```
getline(cin, currInput);
```

If you're starting out programming this is probably what you want to do anyway.

If you feel gutsy, read this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

You'll notice that `getline` returns the stream you pass in. Which will evaluate to `true` as far the loop is concerned.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment.
I  know that's not the right way to write this code, I wanted to simplify a more complex code for the question.
It doesn't enter an infinite loop, it exits and return 0 without printing the last line.

Comment: oh, lol. You said "(New to C++)" so I imagined you were brand spanking new.

Comment: @KobiT If that's the case, then the SIGHUP link is a good way to go. Understand how to handle the signal.

Comment: how does this code work without handling it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756968/reading-multiple-lines-from-a-file-using-getline
In which cases should I handle it?
I've seen many examples of while loop with getline and none of them mentioned it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool explains how functions which  return an `istream` are *designed* to work with conditionals and `while` statements.

Comment: Thanks, @rici. My interpretation of the istream return from the `getline` call is wrong. It should be obvious by now I don't do C++ often.

Comment: Jerry, since OP's code actually works (in a terminal), you might want to consider editting your answer.