# App Store can not close my Qt application

Tags: macos, qt, app-store

App Store can not close my application (which I send there) if update exists.

App Store asks me "Can I close this application?". I say "Yes". It hangs for some seconds and next ask me again "Can I close this application?"

I saw OSX event logs, but there are nothing

```
Qt 5.4
OSX 10.10.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The App store probably sends a `SIGTERM` signal to notify your process to close. Because you are not handling it, nothing happens. You need to implement a unix signal handler as shown in this [*"Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers"* tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

Something like this **untested** mess:

```
int setup_unix_signal_handlers()
{
    struct sigaction term;

    term.sa_handler = ::termSignalHandler;
    sigemptyset(&term.sa_mask);
    term.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;

    return sigaction(SIGTERM, &term, 0);
}

void termSignalHandler(int)
{
    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setup_unix_signal_handlers();
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comprehensive explanation of signal handling : [Simple Linux Signal Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942034/simple-linux-signal-handling)

Comment: I did so, but termSignalHandler doesn't call when I put command "kill -SIGTERM PID"